# How to get the variable a function is assigned to?

Tags: function, lua, variable-assignment, assign

I need to get the variable a function's return value is assigned to.

```
function example()

end
variable = 3           --just for example    
variable = example()   --I need the value of variable(in this case 3) passed as an argument to example()
```

Comment: You want to *automagically* have a function call know about the variable its result is going to be stored into? That's not possible. It isn't even sensible. There may not even *be* a variable its result is going to be stored into. Can you not just use `example(variable)`?

Comment: Yeah, i just wanted to know if Theres a Hacky way to do so .

Comment: Cause you could write easy to use modules.

Comment: No, that wouldn't be "easy to use". That would be "entirely opaque and insane". If you want to use *known* **global** variables for state you **can** do that but it is also generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the Lua reference on how to call and define functions.

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.10
https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.11

You can simply do this:

```
function fancyFunction(val)
  return val
end

local val = 3
val = fancyFunction(val)
```

of course this minimum example does not make much sense. You should of course have another return value than your argument. Otherwise you don't have to call the function in the first place.

Comment: I think you got me wrong. Im no beginner. I just wanted to know if Theres a hacky way ,in your example, take val as an argument for the function, without including it in the brackets. Maybe with reading from a the variable stack or smth in that direction. I wanted to know if its possible becaude im writing a module and tried to make the usage more simple. But anyways i dont need it anymore.  Anyways THX for your answer.

Comment: @Clyybber then you might think about posting questions that are clear...
the argument of a function is what is in its parentheses by definiton...

Answer (score 0):

(Quite hard to understand what you're trying to do.) Could you possibly be referring to object oriented programming? If so, then you need something like this:

```
--setup
t = {}
function t:set(v) self.value = v end              --assign value to 'variable'
function t:get() return self.value end

--use
t:set(3)
print(t:get())
```